# Im new to python and I cant seem to use "else"

Tags: python

So in new to python and i'm studying A-level computing and our language to lean is python.
I'm really far behind and i don't know anything. Despite already being 2 terms in already and only 4/5 months left till examination period.
So I've been watching a video tutorial and for some reason i cant use "else"
![Here is what the tutorial has done, I've copied everything out][1]

Here is what the tutorial has done:

```
sister_age = 15

brother_age = 12

if sister_age > brother_age:


 print" "sister is older"

else:

   print "brother is older"
```

This the out comes of this is "sister is older

However i have copied it out:

```
sister_age=15

 brother_age=12

 if sister_age>brother_age:

print("sister is older")

   else:
```

Then an error message occurs saying the following:

> "SyntaxError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Im sorry but i just don't understand.
Thanks alot, for your time to read this.

Comment: Try indenting your code

Comment: Just to make things clear: in Python, indentation is not cosmetic, it's part of the syntax and is used to indicate the beginning and end of a code block in conditionals (if/else), loops, try/except, functions and class definitions etc.

Answer (score 1):

Indentation is the key.

```
sister_age = 15
brother_age = 12
if sister_age > brother_age:
    print "sister is older"
else:
    print "brother is older"
```